# Xcode 6 beta build fails after adding -Bridging-Header

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

Trying to build framework implemented with Obj-c for Swift. 
I set "Defines Module" flag to YES and added Bridging headers. I checked, in Code Generation section the header exists.

When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -XlinkerLibtool build/MYFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libMYFramework.a normal x86_64

cd /Users/davitohanyan/myframework/MYFrameworkiOS

export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/davitohanyan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYFramework-crutnhhcbfrzpygbpvotdwivtwvm/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/davitohanyan/myframework/MYFrameworkiOS/build/MYFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MYFramework.LinkFileList -ObjC -weak_framework <AdSupport.framework> -L/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -sectalign -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker 4 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker /Users/davitohanyan/myframework/MYFrameworkiOS/build/MYFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MYFramework.swiftmodule -weak_framework AdSupport -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Foundation -o /Users/davitohanyan/myframework/MYFrameworkiOS/build/MYFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYFramework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libMYFramework.a
```

error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Comment: Maybe you have to set the target to something higher that 5.1.1
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1